# spark scala avro write fails with AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-spark

im trying to read data from avro, repartition the data by a field and save it as avro format. below is my sample code. during debugging process, I cannot do a show(10) on my dataframe. it fails with the following error. can someone please help me understand what im doing wrong in my code lines?

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._

val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("s3://test-bucekt/source.avro")

df.show(10)
df.write.partitionBy("partitioning_column").format("avro").save("s3://test-bucket/processed/processed.avro")
```

both show and write fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.shouldPrefetchData(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType;)Z
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:309)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.inputRDD(DataSourceScanExec.scala:305)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec.doExecute(DataSourceScanExec.scala:404)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:375)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
  ... 85 elided
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a caused by an unintendedly binary-incompatible change to FileFormat in emr-5.28.0, which will be fixed when emr-5.29.0 comes out. Fortunately, for the Avro format, there is an easy workaround that can be used in emr-5.28.0. Instead of using the version of spark-avro from Maven Central, it will work if you use the spark-avro jar bundled with EMR. That is, instead of something like `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4`, use `--jars /usr/lib/spark/external/lib/spark-avro.jar`.

Comment: That's a very insightful workaround to use the bundled spark-avro JAR!
Is emr-5.27.0 affected by this? I assume it's also buggy as 5.27.0 is using spark-2.4.4. If your use case allows, it maybe safer to stick with emr-5.26.0 until 5.29.0 is out.

Comment: No, only emr-5.28.0 is affected by this. The bug is specifically in one of EMR's patches on top of Spark 2.4.4 in emr-5.28.0, not in Spark 2.4.4 itself.

Comment: BTW, both emr-5.28.1 and emr-5.29.0 are available now, and both have the fix for this issue. Please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html.

Answer (score 1):

spark-avro for spark 2.4.4 and scala 2.11.12 appears to be buggy. Downgrading to spark 2.4.3 and scala 2.11.12 works just fine

Answer (score 1):

this drove me a bit crazy and couldn't get help from AWS.  Latest version of Spark 2.4.4 definitely has issues with Avro.  Downgrading to 2.4.3 fixed the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is due to jars Compatibility of Spark and Spark-Avro.
Use the correct dependencies of Spark and Avro from maven central.

Spark-Avro package is available from only Spark 2.4.0 version onwards.
Check your Spark version either in pom.xml or build.sbt

The following link provides information about Spark Avro binary in maven central:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro

Comment: I had the correct version defined in my `build.sbt` looks like 2.4.4. has some issues with spark-avro. I downgraded the cluster to 2.4.3 along with `build.sbt` im able to do `df.select` however, `df.show` still fails but with new error message. 

```Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 29, ip-10-255-50-25.corp.tenablesecurity.com, executor 19): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is different exception due to "Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array."  The original exception due to incompatibility is fixed.